# Program verification in Python

Tags: python, hoare-logic

I'm teaching a course on FOL and program verification inspired by the book Mordechai Ben-Ari, *Mathematical Logic for Computer Science*, Springer, 1993-2012. I would like to illustrate notions by having the students program in Python.

For FOL I am using NLTK, which has an excellent FOL package.

But I haven't found yet a Python package for *program verification*: inserting precondition and postcondition logical formulas, find loop invariants, verifying a Python program step by step, etc. In other words, to use a Hoare logic framework inside Python and for Python programs.

Do you know of any package for this task?

Comment: ummmm unittest + mock ?

Comment: FOL == First Order Logic?

Comment: Yes, FOL = First Order Logic, sorry for taking that for granted

Answer (score 1):

Are you going to teach an MOOC on program verification? Or is it going to be a regular classroom with a screen for displaying code? Will you have a white-board at your disposal?

If you are willing to use additional tools, then Online Python Tutor, developed by Prof. Philip Guo (http://www.pythontutor.com/) is an excellent tool. The tool lets you step through the program execution, showing program 'state' (variables and their concrete values). As for as I know, it does not directly allow you to specify/infer pre/post conditions or loop invariants. So, I can see a case where *you*, as a teacher, write pre/post conditions on a board, step through the program and explain the class that the conditions indeed hold true *by showing concrete values of variables using python tutor*. Almost similar approach can be used for showing loop invariants.

Having said this, pythontutor is rapidly getting popular and asking the creator about additional features might just do the trick!